Can we set the components of a parametrized equation to be vectors?
Assume I have a polynomial function $y=f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ for $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$. In order to investigate the curve, I parametrize the equation as such $(t,x(t),y(t))$. Now, If I were to construct a position vector over the curve $\vec{r}=x(t)\vec{e_1}+y(t)\vec{e_2}$ can I also describe the position vector as $\vec{r}=(\vec{x(t)},\vec{x(t)})$?

This would be inventing new notation (which clashes with already existing notation!) So if you need to write things like that you would have to be very clear that you are using a new, nonstandard definition of what $(\cdot,\cdot)$ means. Of course such things sometimes are needed in mathematics, but you don't explain why you would want it here...
